# Ubuntu, Linux Mint тормозят после сборки

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

Даже не знаю как бороться, только перезагрузка помогает после сборки Android. Собралась прошивка, система стоит в простое, нагрузки на винт нет, как только начинаю делать какое-то действие сразу бешеная нагрузка на винт, всё открывается минутами, виснет даже анимация. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: бешенная нагрузка на винт похожа на недостаток опертивки. посмотрите сколько памяти занимет это приложение и сколько свапа вообще в это время используется в системе

Comment: Перезагрузка помогает?

Comment: Я имею ввиду - после перезагрузки всё тормозит так же или это наблюдается только после сборки?

Comment: Это только до перезагрузки, и только после сборки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была забита оперативка. После её очистки система стала работать нормально.

```
sudo su
sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```